# Installation of protoc-gen-grpc-web

Tags: grpc-web

I am currently working on using grpc-web to write a simple client for my service. I have created a service.proto file which was successfully compiled using protoc. The problem arose when I tried to generate the gRPC-Web service client stub using the plugin protoc-gen-grpc-web which doesnt work despite having installed the latter.

Got the following error :

```
protoc -I=./ service.proto --grpc-web_out=import_style=commonjs,mode=grpcwebtext:./
protoc-gen-grpc-web: program not found or is not executable
--grpc-web_out: protoc-gen-grpc-web: Plugin failed with status code 1.
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to make the `protoc-gen-grpc-web` plugin executable and move it to a directory that is discoverable from your `PATH` environment variable.

From [grpc-web/README](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web#code-generator-plugin):

> For example, in MacOS, you can do:
>
> ```
> $ sudo mv ~/Downloads/protoc-gen-grpc-web-1.2.1-darwin-x86_64 \  
> /usr/local/bin/protoc-gen-grpc-web
> $ chmod +x /usr/local/bin/protoc-gen-grpc-web
> ```

Comment: That's what I did, still same message personally

Comment: This worked for me

Answer (score 3):

I'm using MacOS. You need to install this first with brew

```
$ brew install protoc-gen-grpc-web
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't even have to install the plugin globally and make it discoverable from your `PATH`:

`protoc` accepts `--plugin` arguments to point to a required plugin. For `protoc-gen-grpc-web` (as for many others) there's even `npm` support, so you can get it with `npm i --save-dev protoc-gen-grpc-web` and then run `protoc` with `--plugin=protoc-gen-grpc-web=./node_modules/.bin/protoc-gen-grpc-web`

Answer (score 1):

The best solution that I could use for Linux based system was globally installing protoc-gen-grpc-web. This directly takes the files from the /bin of the node_modules files created globally across your system

```
sudo npm install -g protoc-gen-grpc-web
```