# how to install protoc-gen-grpc-web

Tags: grpc, protoc

i'm calling grpc-web in a build script, building an image for docker on ubuntu:

```
protoc -I. graph_endpoint.proto --grpc web_out=import_style=commonjs,mode=grpcwebtext:.
```

it throws an error:

```
protoc-gen-grpc-web: program not found or is not executable
--grpc-web_out: protoc-gen-grpc-web: Plugin failed with status code 1.
```

so i'm trying to install grpc-web. i've tried both methods described here: [Installation of protoc-gen-grpc-web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60388933/installation-of-protoc-gen-grpc-web).
i have `protoc-gen-grpc-web-1.4.2-linux-x86_64` from https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/releases in `/usr/local/bin/protoc-gen-grpc-web`. chmod is set. same error.

any ideas for how to get this plugin working?

Comment: What happens when you invoke the plugin directly (`protoc-gen-grpc-web version`)? `version` isn't always supported but, if it's not, it should throw an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was that i created a directory called "protoc-gen-grpc-web" rather than renaming the binary and placing it directly in bin.